Does there exist a polynomial that extracts the highest digit of an integer in base p?
Given an odd prime $p$, a positive integer $1 \lt n$, and an integer $x \in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, does there exist an an integer-coefficient polynomial that extracts the highest digit of $x$?
The extracted digit can be either $\bmod p^n$ or $\bmod p$.

For example, if the result is $\bmod p^n$,
$$
f(x)=x-(x\bmod {p^{n-1}})\bmod p^n.
$$ This $f(x)$ actually clears the lower digits of $x$. Suppose $x=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_ip^i$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is each digit of $x$, then $f(x)$ maps $x=(x_{n-1},x_{n-2},\ldots,x_1,x_0)$ to $(x_{n-1},0,\ldots,0,0)$.

If the result is $\bmod p$, then $f(x)$ maps $x=(x_{n-1},x_{n-2},\ldots,x_1,x_0)$ to $x_{n-1}$.


Does either of these polynomials $f(x)$ exist? Thanks in advance.

The elements of ${\bf Z}/p^n{\bf Z}$ are not integers; they are cosets of the subgroup $p^n{\bf Z}$ in the group \bf{Z}. Perhaps you mean $x$ is an integer, $0\le x<p^n$.

Yes, I think $0\leq x \lt p^n$ is what I meant. The $x$ is the same as in this question, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269239/lowest-degree-of-polynomial-that-removes-the-first-digit-of-an-integer-in-base-p/269282#269282
, but I wonder if there exists such $f(x)$ that extracts (or removes) the highest digit of $x$.

@Kimball I don't think you can actually get "whatever you want" with integer-coefficient polynomials. For example, you can't have f(0)=f(1)=0, f(2)=1.

@Kimball, thanks for your advice. But just like Hugh Thomas says, integer-coefficient polynomials are not expressive for arbitary functions. Also, I found one report claiming that it is impossible finding such $f(x)$ which removes the lower $r$ digits for some $1\lt r \lt n$, https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/677.pdf.

@Kimball There are functions from the set $(\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z})\to (\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z})$ that are not expressible as polynomials $\bmod p^e$. This is precisely because $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. This is relevant in lattice-based cryptography (specifically "Bootstrapping for BGV/BFV-type cryptosystems"), as shown in OP's link.

@Kimball See for example Kempner's Polynomials and their Residue Systems for some (admittedly more mathematically precise than the current question) exposition on this.

@HughThomas Ah right, I wasn't restricting to polynomials/$\mathbb Z$.

@Mark Schultz-Wu Thanks for your explanation. The $f(x)$ in the link is indeed constructed for the bootstrapping in BGV (specifically for the digit removal). By extending the proof offered by Michael Griffin in that post, if we want to extract the highest digit by removing the lowest $n-1$ digits, the degree of polynomial will be rather high and the coefficient will not strictly be integers. I am not sure if there are other ways to construct an integer-polynomial that maps $(x_{n-1},x_{n-2},...,x_1,x_0)$ to $(x_{n-1},0,...,0,0)$ or $(0,x_{n-2},...,x_1,x_0)$ or just simply $x_{n-1}$.

For a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients, $a-b$ divides $f(b) - f(a) $. Consider $a=p^{n-1}, b=a-p$. Then highest digits of $b, a$ differ modulo $p$, a contradiction.
But I admit that I misundetstood the question.

Thanks for your nice answer! I see that finding a $f(x)$ that directly extracts the highest digit is not feasible in this setting. Is it safe to say that removing the highest digit is just as hard as extracting the highest digit? So that no $f(x)$ can map $x=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x_ip^i$ to $x=(0,x_{n-2},...,x_1,x_0)$ either?

The highest digit of $a$ is $1$ and of $b$ is $p-1$, so they do differ. The contradiction is that $p$ doesn't divide into $p-2$.
